# Можно ли вызвать или создать окошко с редактирование font без дополнительных библиотек

Tags: python, tkinter

Можно ли создать это.
Насколько я знаю в стандартной библиотеке tkinter нет fontdialog который вызавет окошко с шрифтами.
Так что если возможно, то напишите пример с одним видом шрифта как на картинке или хотя объясните как это возможно реализовать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это как раз и есть дополнительная библиотека, мне это не подходит

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue28694

Comment: Ну если только самому не сделать. Просто как мне кажется в `tkinter` нету подобного рода функций их можно самому реализовать только(правда слишком запористо, но можно)

Comment: В этом та я вся штука, реализовывать самому. Можете для образца пожалуйста написать код в ответ на мой вопрос, который будет менять текст только на один вид шрифта, стиль этого шрифта, размер шрифта, нижнее подчеркивание, перечеркивание, а также где можно найти стандартные виды шрифтов для ПК что бы я мог их от туда брать

Comment: @Twiss если вы по ссылке пройдёте, то там говорится что есть tk fontchooser команда и приведён пример её использования из Питона в файле `fontchooser.py` Просто запустите файл и посмотрите что получится.

Comment: Да. Вы правы, но там ещё надо разобраться

Answer (score 0):

это ссылка на код которая реализует то что я хочу 
https://github.com/j4321/tkFontChooser/blob/master/tkfontchooser.py